# How to Converter String to Integer having dots in java

Tags: java, string, format, int

I want converter a string to integer with string having dots:

```
String str = "10.000.000"; //Input is a String
//Output is a integer
int number;
//number = 10000000;
```

Comment: I have edited away the 'dot' tag, as this tag is inappropriate for your question.  You are not asking about the DOT graphical representation language.  Please choose your tags with care.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should give you what you're looking for.

```
String str = "10.000.000";
int number = Integer.parseInt(str.replace(".", ""));
```

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing is: parsing a number with the conventions of a country that is not the US.

The number format with dots as thousands-separators is used, for example, in Germany. You can do:

```
NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
int i = fmt.parse("10.000.000").intValue();
System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String strNumber = str.replace(".",""); // Remove dots
int number = Integer.parseInt(strNumber); // Parse String to number
```